# netty does not honor preferDirect property when calling ioBuffer() methods

Tags: netty

I was debugging an issue with Netty 4.1 where I was getting errors from Netty about Java running out of direct memory, and one thing I did as an attempt to fix the issue was to pass `false` for the `preferDirect` constructor parameter of `PooledByteBufAllocator`. However, I found that this had no material impact—Netty was still throwing the direct memory errors. After doing some more digging, I found that Netty was not honoring the `preferDirect` property when creating "IO buffers" through the `AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer()` methods. This puzzles me. Is this a bug? If not, can a Netty author explain why not? In the end, I subclassed `PooledByteBufAllocator` and override the `ioBuffer()` methods to return heap-based buffers when `preferDirect` is `false`.